# Plugin to help copy/paste XML in android studio according to some pattern?

Tags: regex, xml, android-studio, plugins, copy-paste

I use android studio for creating android apps. While designing the UI I mostly find myself copy pasting my custom made components to test different things out and to see how would they look when I actually populate the view with my component using some adapter. But when I duplicate my components I manually have to update there id's and other attributes in XML according to needs. But those changes mostly have some sort of pattern which I can always define using a regular expression.

**So, in short is there any tool for android studio that can help me copy/paste XML by defining some pattern via regex or something else ?**

*Or should I see this as an opportunity to create my own plugin and start coding right away.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android Studio (Version 3.3+) supports **Live Templates**, that you can make as per your use. These can be for .java as well as .xml file formats. See [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4rI4tTd7-J8) official Android Developer Youtube channel.

**More resources regarding templates in Android Studio**:

- [How to make your own file templates in Android Studio](https://riggaroo.co.za/custom-file-templates-android-studio/) - This is
  a multi-part post.
- [Supercharging your app development speed with
  custom file templates](https://android.jlelse.eu/supercharging-your-app-development-speed-with-custom-file-templates-3e6acb6db6c3)
- [A collection of some Android Studio Live
  Templates](https://github.com/kirtan403/android-studio-live-templates) - This is a Github repo.

You can also try to make repeatedly used classes, activities etc into a library package and reuse them across your projects. Add some tests to them to make sure they work as intended and with some CI/CD scripting and gradle plugins (like [gradle-use-latest-versions-plugin](https://github.com/patrikerdes/gradle-use-latest-versions-plugin)) you can have them automatically upgrade to use latest dependency versions etc. Then all you'd need to do is pull them from a repository or include them as a library in your projects to reduce code redundancy.

Hope this helps.